# Can you detect DOM events on sibling nodes from within an iframe to protect against clickjacking?

Tags: javascript, forms, security, iframe, clickjacking

Is it possible to allow a page from your domain that contains a form to be embedded in a page on a unknown domain and be able to detect DOM events from other elements on that page?

The issue I am trying to investigate is that a malicious party embed the page and then place a clear form over the top of our embedded form (so called [click-jacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking)).

The problem is that the form is intended to be embedded in third-party websites, so can't be restricted through use of X-Frame-Option headers. Even if we ask users to register their domains, a malicious user could just register their domain!

So I am looking for a way to detect if a DOM event such as keydown has been prevented from propagating to my form component, but as the clear form overlay would be a sibling element and outside the scope of the iframe, I fear there is no way of doing this.

I understand the concept of frame-busting (but our embed is meant to be in a frame) and the concept of restricting access to certain domains (but as mentioned, this won't help), but wonder if anyone has experience of allowing embedding of forms and how to protect the form once embedded.

Comment: Is Content-Security-Policy: input-protection the way to go, for example?